# passing a variable form id from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I'm trying to pass a dynamically created id from a form to JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".button-call").click(function() {
    var fld = "<?= $div_id;?>";
    var test = $(fld).val();
        alert(test);
...

<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" class="tb" name="<?php echo $div_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $div_id; ?>" value="" maxlength="80" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="button-call" name="p_k2" id="p_k2" />
</form>
```

alert(test) shows: undefined.

when I change it to alert(fld) I get two alerts, first it shows an empty box, then the correct $div_id

what am I doing wrong??

EDIT 1: I'm trying to display the text from the input...

EDIT 2: this is the complete JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".button-call").click(function() {
    //var fld = "<?= $div_id;?>";
    var fld = "input[name=<?=$div_id;?>]";
    //var fld = "#<?=$div_id;?>";
    var test = $(fld).val();
    var dataString = 'content='+ test;

    alert(fld);
    alert(test);

    if(test=='')
    {
        alert("Write some text ...");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#flash").show();
        $("#flash").fadeIn(1000).html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle"> <span class="loading"> Loading ...</span>');

      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "p_k2.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
      $("#divToRefresh").after(html);
      document.getElementById(fld).value='';
      document.getElementById(fld).focus();
      $("#flash").fadeOut(1000);
      }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

EDIT 3: this is the example I'm using: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/05/insert-and-load-record-using-jquery-and.html 
everything works OK if I use fixed id. But can't get it working with dynamically created id.

EDIT 4:
OK, there are many answers, but non of them seem to be working. I'll try to simplify.

I'll get back to this example, the one I started with (http://www.9lessons.info/2009/05/insert-and-load-record-using-jquery-and.html).

My website is something similar to Facebook. You have friends, and on your 'wall' page you have many different comment boxes (for each of your friends). 
To make ID's of those comment boxes different from one another (to avoid posting something to all your friends) I had to use friend id's from database (`input type="text" class="tb" name="<?php echo $div_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $div_id; ?>" value=""`). That part works OK.

I can get that id to the JavaScript (`var fld = "input[name=<?=$div_id;?>]";`) but, I can't read the value of that text field. Once I do that, I'll take care of inserting that to my database...

Comment: look at my answer, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var fld = "input[name=<?=$div_id;?>]";
```

or better

```
var fld = "#<?=$div_id;?>";
```

Comment: first option shows two alerts, again. first one: input[name=], and the second: input[name=correct_div_id]... second shows nothing, and firebug shows: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Comment: What does `$div_id` contain? `alert($("input[name='some_name']").val());` should work

Comment: It contains id from mysql database. I have comment boxes, similar to facebook. There are lots of comment boxes on one page, that's why I had to put a dynamically created id's. It does show the correct value from the textbox on the second alert!

Comment: can you post a sample script and html outputted by your application on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: if I put only the JavaScript part this is what I get as a result: }); //]]> ... not sure how this site works...

Comment: hum, can you give an exact example how an id from database looks like?

Comment: Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/6a459/ I can't see there any problems!? (I've replaced `<?=;$div_id;?>` with your example of `d251_200`

Comment: yeah, it really does. but <?=$div_id;?> gives me an empty one, then a correct one... like before. I guess I'll give up and try to find a completely different way to do this :(

Comment: Could you have a look at your source code in browser (when opened your page) and can you say me, if there still stands `<?=$div_id;?>` (in Javascript part and in HTML part)

Comment: both say the id value: d251_200

Comment: here it is: <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" class="tb" name="d5082_199" id="d5082_199" value="" maxlength="80" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="button-call" name="p_k2" id="p_k2" />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".button-call").click(function() {
    var fld = "input[name=d5082_199]";
    var test = $(fld).val();
    alert(fld);
    alert(test);

Comment: There is still no problem, see http://ideone.com/6dGOd (there is dynamic code, which replaces `$div_id` with your example). When you copy and paste the result output to http://htmledit.squarefree.com/ then all is fine. If this still solves not your problem, then there may be an other problem in your source, which has nothing to do with this question

Comment: thanks rabudde, the code does work... not the way I wanted it to work, but still, it works. I had to change the position of the script to avoid the problem I had with the first alert being empty. I figured it out once you asked me to look at the html output of the browser. thanks for your help. The only bad thing about this is that I'll have to figure another way to do what I planned to :( Thank you, and the other guys for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = $("#"+fld).val();
alert(test);
```

Comment: sure, but as you can see, he wants to get content from input field into variable `test`

Comment: what's different from my solution?

Comment: have a look at the example from edit3. I can't get it working with variable id of <input type="text" ...

Comment: @rabudde: I do not look at everyone's answer, so I'm not sure if you have exactly the same. I just edited it

Comment: @Alex: look at your fld = '?' and tell us what ? contains

Comment: genesis, I didn't understand your last comment

Comment: @Alex: show us that part of code where you use php to fill js variable

Comment: <input type="text" class="tb" name="<?php echo $div_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $div_id; ?>" value="" maxlength="80" />

Comment: <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" class="tb" name="d5082_199" id="d5082_199" value="" maxlength="80" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="button-call" name="p_k2" id="d5082_199" />
</form>

Comment: @Alex: your code contains id="d5082_199" twice but it's not visible in your question. So delete that one id="d5082_199" and it will be fine

Comment: <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" class="tb" name="d5082_199" id="d5082_199" value="" maxlength="80" />
 <input type="submit" value="Send" class="button-call" name="p_k2" id="p_k2" />
</form>  ...this doesn't help either

Answer (score 1):

you can use $(this) inside the click event handler.

i.e.

```
$(".elementClass").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

will return the id of the .elementClass that was clicked.

Comment: this helps a bit if change the button id to my variable id... $(function() {
  $(".button-call").click(function() {
    var fld = $(this).attr("id");
    var test = $("#"+fld).val();
    alert(test);